# Quarkus: How to log body of an incoming POST request

Tags: netty, quarkus, vert.x, resteasy

I have a Quakus application that uses `quarkus-resteasy` dependency. i.e non-reactive.

I want to print(or somehow know) the content of the incoming POST request body.

I tried various log level settings like below:

```
quarkus.log.level=ALL
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.resteasy".level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."org.apache.http".level=TRACE
quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider".level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson".level=TRACE
```

All that I can get is request URI details and response code details.

I also implemented a logging filter as suggested [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#the-jakarta-rest-way). But that also printed empty body. Here is my implementation.

```
package com.crux.kiron.util.common;

import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;



@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class);

    @Context
    UriInfo info;

    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {

        final String method = context.getMethod();
        final String path = info.getPath();
        final String address = request.remoteAddress().toString();

        Future<Buffer> body = request.body();
        body.onComplete(ar -> {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                /*...*/
            } else {
                LOG.info("Request body: " + ar.result());
            }
        });


        LOG.info("Extralog "+method+" "+path+" "+address+" "+body);
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone can throw some light on this. It actually should be as easy as turning on debug log for a certain package. But it seems much more involved.

Answer (score 2):

I did this once upon a time by implementing the ReaderInterceptor interface in the ext package. As I remember (I don't have access to the source code anymore), I consumed the body (and could log it) using the getInputStream() method on the ReaderInterceptorContext object, but as the body was now consumed I had to re-instate it by "setting it back" using the setInputStream(...) method, to allow the next actors to read the body.

I have no idea how this will play with vertx.

Consuming the body of an HTTP request is, in the general case, rather tricky.  It could potentially go on forever, so you have to be careful on what resources you apply this decorator.